# Monaca compiled app iOS app as 32 bit, not 64 bit

Tags: ios, iphone, monaca

I recently created an app that's pure HTML/JS/CSS. Aside from have an asset of a custom font, everything is native to Monaca. When I compile the app and load it into my iPhone 7, my iPhone warns that the app is a 32-bit app and may be disabled. I can't locate where in Monaca I can change how to compile it any differently. Thanks in advance for any help or pointers.

Comment: plz check this, hope its helpful. http://www.chupamobile.com/blog/2015/01/19/convert-app-64-bit-requirement/

Answer (score 0):

If your project is using Cordova 6.2 or later, the `release` build of this project should be 64-bit. However, if you use `debug` or `adhoc` build, it will be 32-bit; then, the warning message will be showing.